# Changing Column Name in Database and Keeping ComponentModel DisplayNames in .edmx Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

So I made a little relational database with about seven tables, and I'm using some of these to make a form.  So I made an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to diagram the forms and generate classes based on the tables.  Now I want to give the class properties DisplayNames (using System.ComponentModel).  The forms also get pretty big, and there's a lot of DisplayNames.

```
public partial class ParticularForm
{
    public System.Guid ParticularForm1 { get; set; }
    public System.Guid GeneralFormFieldsID { get; set; }

    #region Particular Form

    [DisplayName("What's your name?")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("How many friends do you have?")]
    public Nullable<byte> FriendsAmount { get; set; }
    // (etc...)
```

Ack!  So it looks like the ADO.NET Entity Data Model gave one of the columns an incorrect name: "ParticularForm1" should be called "ParticularFormID".  So I go into the database, rename the "ParticularForm" column to "ParticularFormID".  Now I want to update references to `ParticularForm1` in the scaffolded Form.tt classes, changing the name to name `ParticularFormID`.  So here's what I do:

- I go into the Form.edmx diagram and click `Update Model from Database`.  It doesn't allow me to refresh a *single* table, it refreshes all of them at once.  Afterwards I save, and now the .edmx model correctly shows the "ParticularFormID" column.  But it still shows the weird "ParticularForm1" column, and in addition to this, **I've lost like 100 display names.**

So I undo the pending changes in TFS and I take a new approach.

```
public partial class ParticularForm
{
    public System.Guid ParticularFormID { get; set; }
```

- I went back into Form.tt > ParticularForm.cs and change the property's name from ParticularForm1 to ParticularFormID.  Then I go back to the Designer and save the changes. I get the message:

  `This file has been modified outside of the source editor.  Do you want to reload it?`

Sure. Then I get it again **for every table in addition to the only one I changed.**  Every time I click `No`, no changes are made, but TFS still says there are pending changes.  When I click `Yes` for ParticularForm.cs, all of its DisplayNames are removed *again*, and the .cs file reverts back to the prior naming conventions that ADO.NET chose, and undoes my change.

I'd like to keep the work I've already done with respect to the DisplayNames, but **change a single column name** without losing all of my work. Any ideas on what is going on?  Why don't ADO.NET Entity Data Models respect me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that one should [hold the data annotations in a MetadataType class](http://ryanhayes.net/data-annotations-for-entity-framework-4-entities-as-an-mvc-model/).  Not just `[DisplayName()]`, like, everything.

Part of my issue was that I wasn't reading this:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    **Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.**
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```